# Python file string comparison

Tags: python, file-comparison

I am trying to do a string comparison between strings in two text files. The text is produced by bintext application reading from .exe and produce files with format such as below :

> File pos      Mem pos          ID   Text
>
> ========       =======          ==   ====
>
> 00000000004D   00000040004D      0   !This program cannot be run in DOS mode.
>
> 0000000000A0   0000004000A0      0   Rich!

I tried to do a `line.split` with a white space, but as a result the last column content is also separated with white space. Instead of `[!this program cannot be run in dos mode]` I got `[!this,program,cannot,be,run,in,DOS,Mode,.]`

Is there any simple way to put in the array the entire column 3 from the txt file without splitting it ?

Comment: Did you utilize `split`'s count parameter?

Comment: i didnt, i put the count and play around with the parameter and it got the result i wanted. thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
data = []
for line in input_file:
    data.append(line.strip().split(' ', 3))
```

This will give you:

```
['00000000004D', '00000040004D', '0', '!This program cannot be run in DOS mode.']
['0000000000A0', '0000004000A0', '0', 'Rich!']
```

Documentation on [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function

Comment: i used this advice and increased the split count since the file is not exactly separated by one space per column. i tried to post the actual formatting initially but it reads only one space :\ issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), the `str.split` method has an optional `maxsplit` argument which, if gives, specifies that a maximum number of splits that can be performed on the list.

Assuming that you already know how to read the file you can specify a maximum of `3` splits:

```
data = "00000000004D 00000040004D 0 !This program cannot be run in DOS mode."
data.split(None, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the first part of the string has a constant length, using slicing;

```
In [1]: s = '00000000004D 00000040004D 0 !This program cannot be run in DOS mode.'

In [2]: s[28:]
Out[2]: '!This program cannot be run in DOS mode.'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [93]: s = "00000000004D 00000040004D 0 !This program cannot be run in DOS mode."

In [94]: s.rsplit("0",1)[-1] # rsplit once on the 0
Out[94]: ' !This program cannot be run in DOS mode.'

      import re
[96]: re.split("\d\s",s)[-1] # single digit followed by a space
Out[96]: '!This program cannot be run in DOS mode.'
```